# Is it faster to load XML all at once or bit by bit?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, nsxmlparser

A quick question here: is it faster to load a large XML file (just one item per row), about 50,000 items, and parse it client side using JavaScript (I'm trying to find the rows that correspond to a certain date range), or is it faster to have PHP do the pre-parsing and send it to the client as it's needed? The thing is the PHP request would be about once every second, which seems a bit overboard - I'm trying to load points on a map, I expect each date range to have about 2000 points.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are bringing 1,000's of results back to the client every second you are going to have performance issues... That said if you are sending lots of data via AJAX I would recommend using JSON instead as there is much less overhead/content to send across the wire.

You also mentioned filtering on the server... Definitely filter out anything you don't need to send... Until you need to send it.

Comment: The odd thing is that Firefox seems to have a hard time when I do a getJSON as opposed to an XML version (createXmlHttpRequest) for the same exact amount of data - is it because it's trying to cache the content in some form? JSON does have a smaller footprint, however.

Comment: JSON should work fine in Firefox - are you returning the data with the correct content type headers "application/json"?... As for caching, it is actually IE that is historically most aggressive with caching AJAX requests.

Answer (score 2):

Both are dog slow. It seems like you shouldn't be using XML in the first place. Parsing and loading a huge XML takes time, searching the resulting tree too. Use a database, they're made for tasks like this, and they've been optimized for many many years. XML is not a database.

Anyway, caching will help vastly if you're expecting more than one user a day, and you should send the data to the client using a **very** lightweight format (JSON is propably the best bet) to minimize wasted bandwidth.

Comment: The odd thing is that Firefox seems to have a hard time when I do a getJSON as opposed to an XML version (createXmlHttpRequest) for the same exact amount of data - is it because it's trying to cache the content in some form? JSON does have a smaller footprint, however.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  In this case, I'd suggest you measure.